# Finding a general formula for summation

Tags: summation

I am trying to find a general summation for $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(k-1)2^k}{k(k+1)}$$
I tried to expand it and look for some pattern.
$$\frac{(1-1)2^1}{1(1+1)} + \frac{(2-1)2^2}{2(2+1)}+...+\frac{((k-1)-1)2^{k-1}}{(k-1)((k-1)+1} + \frac{(k-1)2^k}{k(k+1)}$$
If it can be solved through telescoping, I couldn't see how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

$$\frac{(k-1)}{k(k+1)}=\frac{2}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k}$$

and therefore

$$\frac{(k-1)2^k}{k(k+1)}=\frac{2^{k+1}}{k+1}-\frac{2^k}{k}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's the whole solution.  I couldn't have figured it out without the hint that $$\frac{(k−1)2^{k}}{k(k+1)}=\frac{2^{k+1}}{k+1}-\frac{2^k}{k}$$  From there the summation can be expanded such that most of the terms factor out and all that's left is $$-2+\frac{2^{k+1}}{k+1}$$

Comment: There is a typo in the first part, we have indeed $$\frac{(k-1)2^k}{k(k+1)}=\frac{2^{k+1}}{k+1}-\frac{2^k}{k}$$